Issue after bootloader on STM32F072RBT6: Stack Pointer not jumping to application address
I am currently working on a project using the STM32F072RBT6 microcontroller, where I have implemented a custom bootloader to load an application program into flash memory. However, after the bootloader successfully writes the application binary, the stack pointer does not correctly jump to the application’s address, and the application fails to execute.
MCU Model: STM32F072RBT6 Bootloader
Functionality: The bootloader receives the application binary and writes it to flash memory at the designated application address.
Application Flash Address: 0x08004000
Problem: After the bootloader completes, I attempt to jump to the application by setting the stack pointer and program counter accordingly, but the application does not start. It appears that the stack pointer is not correctly set to the application's address.
Jump Code in Bootloader:
static void goto_application(void) {
    void (* app_reset_handler)(void) = (void *)(*(volatile uint32_t *) (0x08004000 + 4));

    __disable_irq();

    __set_MSP((*(volatile uint32_t *)0x08004000));

    __enable_irq();

    app_reset_handler();
}


Welcome to SE/EE! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]" and other pages of the [help]. While such questions are commonly asked on [so], it is fine here, too, I assume. -- Did you check the resulting machine code? You can look at a listing, a disassembly, or use your debugger. Please [edit] your question to clarify and to add the disassembly of the function you show.

How have you confirmed that it isn't set correctly? There are many other things that could go wrong too.

The cast is incorrect, it should be ... = (void (*)(void)) (0x08004000 + 4);. Converting function pointers to void* or vice versa is undefined behavior. Converting integers to function pointers is OK though, if the compiler allows it and if the address is corresponding to the function alignment requirement

@Lundin is UB in general, but is well defined in this implementation

@0___________ So not gcc but something else? Hmm. To OP doesn't mention compiler used, so in case of STM32 I'd definitely assume gcc. There is a gcc non-standard extension allowing arithmetic on void pointers and function pointers, which in turn suggests that they must all be boiled down to something like a character pointer internally. ->

But gcc is also massively infamous for abusing undefined behavior whenever it gets a chance and there is no control of it. There's nothing like centralized quality control over the gcc compiler. Some lone gcc dev could release a patch one day and boom - your program goes off into the woods. And when you bug report it they'll go "but this is clearly undefined behavior" and deny any attempt to become a quality implementation. They haven't had a single stable release which wasn't completely filled with bugs since gcc 8 somwhere.

You forgot about one important detail.

you have to set the VTOR register to set the vector table to application one.

Also if the application is run from the bootloader it should enable interrupts itself. Otherwise you will have a gray area when interrupts are enabled and call handlers from the the new vector table - but the app did not have time to initialize itself.
Side note:
void (* app_reset_handler)(void) = (void (*)(void))(0x08004000 + 4));


Yes , I already tried VTOR register to set the vector table to application but problem occured.

@ShyamParmar You don't tell how you tried that. You can't change VTOR without disabling interrupts first in bootloader. And your main app cannot re-enable interrupts before VTOR is set and the environment is up. The startup code will enable interrupts and any pending interrupt will execute from bootloader code or from application code before you change it.

I wanted to take a moment to express my sincere thanks to everyone who contributed their time and expertise to help me with my issue. I’m happy to report that I’ve successfully solved the problem!  In my case problem was Hal_Delay() function not working in application code.
